# Table Removed when pressing button

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am having trouble swapping a value in a table. When I press the button, instead of the value being changed the whole table is removed and I can't figure out why. Below is my code. (rt refers to a reagent-table by frozenlock https://github.com/Frozenlock/reagent-table)

```
(ns <namespace name>
  (:require [reagent.core :as reagent :refer [atom]]
            [reagent-table.core :as rt]
            [clojure.walk :as walk]))

(def table-data {:headers ["1" "2" "3" "4"]
                 :rows [["A"]]})

(defonce tdata (atom table-data))

(defn replace-value [struct]
  (walk/prewalk-replace {"A" "hello"} (struct :rows)))

(defn change-value [tdata]
  [:div
   [:input.btn.btn-primary
    {:type     :submit
     :on-click #(swap! tdata replace-value)
     :value    "Change"}]
   ])

(defn tablescreen []
  [:div
   [:div.container
    [:div.span12
     [rt/reagent-table tdata]
     [change-value tdata]]]
   ])
```

Initally on the screen it shows the table. However, when pressing the button, I expected "A" to change to "hello". However, when pressing the button the whole table is removed from the view and only the button is left

Comment: i guess that is because you swap the whole table data with the updated :rows value. (replace-value would return `[["hello"]]` instead of updated table. what you need to do is something like `(update struct :rows #(prewalk-replace {"A" "hello"} %))` in your `replace-value` function. (not tested)

Comment: @leetwinski I tested it and that is indeed the case. For the code above it means: `(defn replace-value [struct]
  (walk/prewalk-replace {"A" "hello"} struct))` (remove `:rows`).